# Where is / where do I put the common library?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin, cross-platform

I am writing my first cross-platform app with Xamarin on Azure using Visual Studio 2017.

I've found a great walkthrough article by Adrian Hall at:

https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter1/firstapp_pc/

However, I have got the following stage and I'm stumped:

"Once the project is created, you will see that four new projects have been created: a common library which you named plus one project for each platform that has been chosen. Since we chose a project with three platforms, we get four projects:"

[image]

The next stage is the problem, entitled "Building the Common Library"... he writes:

"Let's start with the cloud service - this is defined in Abstractions\ICloudService.cs. It is used for initializing the connection and getting a table definition:"

My question is where is the common library into which I put "Abstractions\ICloudService.cs" or if the common library needs building, where do I put the common library files in a cross platform app like this??

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once the project is created, you will see that four new projects have been created: a common library which you named plus one project for each platform

It works *exactly* like the documentation says.  TodoList is your common library.  TodoList.{Platform} are your platform projects.